# Java.util.HashMap -- why HashMap extends AbstractMap and implement Map?

Tags: java, hashmap

why HashMap extends AbstractMap and implement Map ? is extending AbstractMap not sufficient, because AbstractMap implements Map?

Comment: essentially the same question as this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165204/why-does-linkedhashsete-extend-hashsete-and-implement-sete -- short version: this redundancy has an impact on how Javadoc gets generated.

Comment: I was spurred to investigate, and actually, Javadoc was not the issue. New short version: it was just a mistake.

Comment: Heh. I asked about this today too. I was told that it was a "well-intentioned mistake", and that the original reasoning was the interface versus implementation thing I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is redundant. I suspect that it was done for "documentation" reasons. HashMap implements Map, and you can rely on that. The fact that it extends AbstractMap is arguably just an implementation detail. (Though it's extremely unlikely that future versions of HashMap would not extend AbstractMap, since there probably *some* code out there that expects HashMap to be assignable to AbstractMap.)

Answer (score 0):

It is redundant, but doesn't hurt. If they do not want to implement `Map` in `AbstractMap` in future, it will still work.

Comment: Except that's a breaking change - somewhere someone will have done `Map map=objectOfTypeAbstractMap`.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing is that AbstractMap is an implementation detail. It could be absent in a future version of Oracle's JDK.. It could be absent in a current version of IBM's JDK.. But whether it is present or not, the HashMap should always conform to the List contract.. So, it is explicitly captured in class declaration by specifying 'HashMap implements Map'