# Why does AtomicInteger implements Serializable

Tags: java, numbers, integer

Accoriding to javadoc,

```
public class AtomicInteger extends Number implements java.io.Serializable {

// code for class

}
```

But,

```
public abstract class Number implements java.io.Serializable {
//code for class
}
```

If `Number` class already implements `java.io.Serializable` then why do `AtomicInteger` implements it again?

**Edit:** Does Serializable being a marker interface makes any difference in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to document it more clearly. [Same situation with the abstract collection base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294519/java-util-hashmap-why-hashmap-extends-abstractmap-and-implement-map).

[Could also have been a mistake initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165204/why-does-linkedhashsete-extend-hashsete-and-implement-sete?lq=1) (that is now carried forward for consistency's sake).

Answer (score 2):

There is no necessity as such, it is just for the sake of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice, and more for readable purpose. The same case with `HttpServlet` and `GenericServlet`. There are lot of other implementations in java sdk which follows this.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Serializable being a marker interface makes any difference in this context?

No difference at all.  There is nothing special about a marker interface at the linguistic level.