# Java: why does WeakHashMap implement Map whereas it is already implemented by AbstractMap?

Tags: java, collections, weakhashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java.util.HashMap — why HashMap extends AbstractMap and implement Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294519/java-util-hashmap-why-hashmap-extends-abstractmap-and-implement-map)
>   [Why would both a parent and child class implement the same interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668429/why-would-both-a-parent-and-child-class-implement-the-same-interface)

**WeakHashMap<K,V>** is declared to both extend **AbstractMap<K,V>** and implement **Map<K,V>**.

But **AbstractMap<K,V>** already implements **Map<K,V>**. It looks like the `implements` declaration is redundant.

What is the reason it was declared?

Comment: Redundancy for documentation.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668429/why-would-both-a-parent-and-child-class-implement-the-same-interface

Comment: Did you see that in the documentation or in the implementation itself?

Comment: @fge: It's in the source code of the Oracle JDK. It's really written as `public class WeakHashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barring someone being able to point to a reason posted online somewhere by the authors of `WeakHashMap` in the JDK, we can only speculate. The speculation is that it improves the auto-generated documentation. It has no effect on the interfaces exposed by the class or how you use it.

Comment: The generated javadoc for a class depends on the doclet class used, and it happens that the default doclet queries for interfaces "deeply", so it does not matter whether you omit redundant interfaces or not: they will apear in the javadoc.

Comment: @fge: I ain't disagreein'. :-) I want to believe the Sun engineers (as was) did this for a reason. I don't, but I want to...

Answer (score 2):

Although it is indeed redundant, it ensures that if the interface implementation is removed from the parent, the child will still hold by the `Map` interface and produce the necessary compile errors.

Comment: If you rebased it, and the new base didn't implement `Map<K,V>`, **and** you didn't add the `implements` and necessary plumbing, that would be a pretty shocking edit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This "looks" like an overlook. If you extend a class, you automatically implement all interfaces implemented by the base class (whether that base class is `abstract` or not). So, given:

```
public interface I {}

public class A implements I {}
```

and you declare:

```
public class B extends A {}
```

the declaration above is strictly equivalent to

```
public class B extends A implements I {}
```

An overlook indeed. Good spotting ;)