# How does LinkedHashMap work under the hood?

Tags: java, oop, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I read about [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and from the description (although very interesting) I couldn't understand how it actually does its job under the hood. As a side note, I know how a `HashMap` works underneath in Java.
So I review the source and still can not figure out how it works. Perhaps I am not grasping something fundamental in OOP in this case so bear with me.
To summarize the part that is confusing to me is the following:
The `LinkedHashMap` delegates all the calls to its parent `HashMap`.
Internally it overrides the `HashMap.Entry` to implement the various `recordAccess` and `recordRemoval` methods which seem to implement the logic of the `LinkedHashMap`
But the actual `Entries` are inside the table of the base class i.e. the `HashMap` which instantiates a table of `HashMap.Entry` and not of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`.
So I can't figure out how the various `recordAccess` and `recordRemove` etc are actually being called.
So can anyone help me understand what's going on here?
Am I correct to think that somehow the `LinkedHashedMap.Entry` is the type of table created by the `HashMap`? But how?

**UPDATE:**
My question is how do the `recordAccess` are being called. My experiment on this using a derived version of `HashMap` failed for the reason of Shengyuan Lu (+1) - My bad there

**UPDATE:**
The following which I tried is the same (I think) as what the `LinkedHashMap` is doing:

```
package delete;  

public class Base<T> {  

    Entry<T>[] table;  
    int idx = 0;  
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public Base(){  
        System.out.println("In base");  
        table = new Entry[10];  
    }

    public void add(T x){  
        table[idx] = new Entry(x);  
        table[idx].doSomething();  
    }  

    static class Entry<T>{  
        T value;  

        Entry(T x){  
            this.value = x;  
            System.out.println("Entry::Base");  
        }

        void doSomething(){  
            System.out.println("In Entry base, doing something");  
        }  
    }  

}  




public class Derived<T> extends Base<T> {  

    static class Entry<T> extends Base.Entry<T>{  

        Entry(T x) {  
            super(x);  
            System.out.println("In Entry derived");  
        }  

        int val;  

        @Override  
        void doSomething() {  
            System.out.println("In Entry derived doing something really smart!");  
        }       
    }  

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Base<String> b = new Derived<String>();  
        b.add("Test string");  

    }  

}
```

But it prints:

```
In base  
Entry::Base     
In Entry base, doing something
```

So the derived `Entry` is never called.
Is my example different somehow? I can't understand how this works for `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Protected or package private?

Comment: for _Why does LinkedHashMap is defined as extends HashMap implements Map_ read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2165204/1393766)

Comment: @Pshemo:Thank you. I updated OP after the explanation of your link. Now all I need is help in my core question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define `MyLinkedHashMap` under package `java.util`, it will compile;)

Because `HashMap.HashEntry` is package visibility.

PLUS:

I think the major thing puzzled you is *LinkedHashMap.Entry* vs *HashMap.Entry*. The point is LinkedHashMap.Entry **is-a** HashMap.Entry. Actually **HashMap.table stores LinkedHashMap.Entry** in LinkedHashMap.

Regarding to `recordAccess` and `recordRemoval`, they both override HashMap.Entry versions. You could find out the references both in LinkedHashMap and HashMap.

Merge comments here: **You sample code is not same as `LinkedHashMap` implementation. See `LinkedHashMap.addEntry()` instead.**

Comment: But how?`HashMap` does `table = new Entry[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];`.

Comment: @user384706 Think about  `Object[] table=new Object[1]; table[0] = "I am subclass of Object"; `

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+F is your friend here, especially when it allows you to search multiple files at once. `recordAccess` is called on the accessed/created entry by the `put` and `get` methods of the map. (The calls are in `HashMap.put`, `HashMap.putForNullKey` and `LinkedHashMap.get`.) It is only relevant if you use the constructor of the LinkedHashMap that takes a boolean parameter and passed `true` to that. The effect of that is, that whenever you touch the map, the touched entry will be moved to the front of the internal linked list.

Quoting the documentation:

> A special constructor is provided to create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently (access-order). This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU caches. Invoking the put or get method results in an access to the corresponding entry (assuming it exists after the invocation completes). The putAll method generates one entry access for each mapping in the specified map, in the order that key-value mappings are provided by the specified map's entry set iterator. No other methods generate entry accesses. In particular, operations on collection-views do not affect the order of iteration of the backing map.
>
> The removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry) method may be overridden to impose a policy for removing stale mappings automatically when new mappings are added to the map.

Similarly `recordRemoval` is called from `HashMap.removeEntryForKey` and `HashMap.removeMapping`.