# what is the design decision behind LinkedHashSet implementation.

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashset

A quick look at javadoc:

```
public class LinkedHashSet<E>     
   extends HashSet<E>     
     implements Set<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Why did they implement Set when it has already been implemented in HashSet?
I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165204/why-does-linkedhashsete-extend-hashsete-and-implement-sete) but I don't believe this was just a mistake.

Comment: Josh was directly asked about that and he said that it was a mistake.

Comment: As I said,  those answers are not convincing.

Comment: Also Einstein did mistakes in his life... why Josh can't?

Comment: Did "they" really implement it over again? If it is just in the class header it doesn't mean the methods have been implemented in LinkedHashSet - they have been inherited.

Comment: then what was the need of  "implements Set<E>" ?

Comment: I did this occasionally to tell the reader of the Javadoc what is implemented *without having to go through some parent classes*. Don't know why "they" did it, but it's a good reason. - Note that HashSet and AbstractSet also have `implements Set<X>`.