# if HashSet is extending Abstract set then why it needs to implement Set?

Tags: java, collections

The below code is bit confusing. AbstractSet already implements Set. So the question is if HashSet is extending Abstract set then why it needs to implement Set?

```
public class HashSet<E>
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Comment: For clarity of the API.

Comment: It does not **need** to redeclare that it implements Set, but it does redeclare...  :- )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165204/why-does-linkedhashsete-extend-hashsete-and-implement-sete